# i have done with python flask api. Now how to create log file to know whenever the api is hit?

Tags: python, api, file, logging, flask

i have created an api with Python and flask. now i am just trying to get the log of api hit. how to do it?

This is for ubuntu server

```
def main():
    file = open(“MY_Log_File__%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%Y.txt”, “w”)
    file.write(“    ”) 
    file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

i want to get a text file in which all the details of the api must be added while it srunning with the file name MY_Log_File__%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%Y.txt

Comment: You can use the Python `logging` module to manage your logs https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html and for the request details you can get the infromation from `flask.request` http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a **new log file each time** including the date use this way;

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

timeStamp = time.time()
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timeStamp).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


def main():
    logFile = open(“MY_Log_File__%s.txt” % (date)
    logFile.write("MY API INFORMATION %s" % (date))
    logFile.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To update an **existing file** use this way:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

timeStamp = time.time()
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timeStamp).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


def main():
    with open("/path/yourLogFile.txt", "a") as logFile:
        logFile.write("MY API INFORMATION %s" % (date))
        logFile.close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: does it add the time and date in the log file name?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a way of adding the date to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

from datetime import datetime

```
def main():
    file = open(“MY_Log_File__%s.txt” %datetime.now().strftime('%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%Y'), “w”)
    file.write(“    ”) 
    file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```